# OSGI bundle - Eclipse project bundling with ALL dependencies

Tags: eclipse, osgi, apache-karaf

I am new to the OSGI world and could use some advice from the experts out there. My aim is to deploy a few servlets along with REST resources into a standard Karaf installation. I am planning to use Grizzly (w/Jersey) as the http container.

I am trying to figure out a way to create an eclipse project, in which I can compile my custom code, and deploy this code along with all dependencies such as Grizzly, Jersey, OSGI frameworks & bundles as a single archive into Karaf.

The end goal is to have a single deployable entity which includes all my code and the dependencies without needing to manually install dependencies in Karaf.

Is this possible or am I looking at it the wrong way? I have been reading up on OBR, features and KAR but not able to put the whole picture together as yet. What would be the best practice wrt achieving this objective?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To give you the general idea regarding embedding and launching a complete OSGi application, I suggest you check out chapter 13 on [this book](http://www.manning.com/hall/). It explains it using Equinox implementation but I hope the overall approach should look similar. If you follow through you will see that you can put all your bundles in a folder where the system will iterate through and install them.